# Kerberos still using default /etc/krb5.conf file even after setting KRB5_CONFIG

Tags: hadoop, kerberos

I do not have access to change the file in /etc/krb5.conf so as a work around I am setting KRB5_CONFIG.

export KRB5_CONFIG=/home/user/keytab/krb5.conf

echo-ing this variable verifies this path is set but when I try to kinit it is still using the /etc/krb5.conf file.

Is there anything else I need to set? Do i need set any specific permissions or restart any service?

The reason I am doing this is because Hadoop does not support non-default realm's.

Comment: If we've answered your question please mark it as such which will verify it to others in the community; otherwise please let us know if any.

Answer (score 7):

You may point to krb5.conf in your location by passing parameter

```
-Djava.security.krb5.conf=/home/user/keytab/krb5.conf
```

There are many ways to pass that JVM property, for example by defining HADOOP_OPTS:

```
export HADOOP_OPTS="$HADOOP_OPTS -Djava.security.krb5.conf=/home/user/keytab/krb5.conf"
```

Answer (score 0):

you have missed "-D" in your answer. Also it is safer to include $HADOOP_OPTS, to not loose previous configuration.
export HADOOP_OPTS="$HADOOP_OPTS -Djava.security.krb5.conf=/home/user/keytab/krb5.conf"

Comment: Could you modify your question with more details?